# Morphism between thick fibers of schemes extends to a neighbourhood

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $ S $ be a locally Noetherian scheme, and $ X $, $ Y $ finite type $ S $-schemes. Let us fix $ s \in S $. Let $ \varphi : X \times _ { S }   \mathcal{O}_{S,s}   \to   Y   \times _ { S }   \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ be a morphism of $ S $-schemes.   Show that there exists  an  open subset $ W \ni s $ of $ S $ and a morphism $ f : X \times _ { S }  W  \to   Y  \times _ { S } W $  such that $ \varphi $ is obtained   from $ f $ via   base  change  $ \text{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{S,s}   \to   W   $. If $ \varphi $ is an isomorphism, show that   there exists such an  $ f  $ which is moreover an isomorphism. 
$ \quad  $

**P.S.** This question is Exercise 2.3.5 from Qing Liu's book and is related to "[Extending a morphism of schemes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259876/extending-a-morphism-of-schemes)", "[Extending a morphism from Spec $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303188/extending-of-morphism-from-spec-mathcalo-x-x?noredirect=1&lq=1)".    I am writing the solution below in order to record some of the details that initially trumped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly less pedantic version of the same solution for quicker future reference.

We can assume that $ X $ and $ S $ are affine, say $ X =  \text{Spec } A $ and $ S = \text{Spec } R $, since $ X $ is quasi-compact and we can shrink $ S $ to an open subset any finite number of times. Denote $ s $ by the prime $ \mathfrak{p} \subset R $.  Let  $ L    = R  \setminus   \mathfrak{p} $. If $ Y $ is affine as well, say $ Y = \text{Spec } B $, the problem just boils down to showing that a map $  L ^ { - 1  }  B  =  B \otimes  R_ { \mathfrak{p}  }  \to     A  \otimes R _ { \mathfrak { p } }       =      L ^ { -  1 }  A  $ actually comes from (i.e. is the localization of) a map $ B_{r} \to A_{r} $ for some $ r \in  L    $ which is not hard using finiteness conditions on $ B $.

In general, we can choose a finite  open affine cover $ V_{i} = \text{Spec } B_{i} $ of $ Y $ for $ i = 1, \ldots, n $.  The   inverse images $ U_{i} ' = \varphi^{-1} ( \text{Spec } ( L  ^ { -1  } B_{i} ) )  $ can be covered with   a  finite  number of open affines of $    \text {Spec  }   L   ^ {- 1 }  A $, which in turn, can be covered with principal  open   affines.      So, altogether we can choose a collection of $ g_{j} \in  L   ^ { -   1  }  A    $ for $ j = 1 , \ldots, m $ such  that $ \text{Spec }  
 (   L ^ { - 1 }  A    ) _ { g_{j } }   $  cover  $  \text{ Spec }  L  ^{-1} A $ and each such open set lands in some $   \text{Spec } {   L   ^  { - 1  }  B_{i} }  $ under $ \varphi  $.   Suppose $ g_{j} =   \frac{x_{j} } { y_{j} } $ for $ x_{j} \in A $, $ y_{j} \in  L $. As $ y_{j} $ is invertible in $  L ^{-1} A $, we can assume $ y_{j} = 1 $.   From  the commutative algebra trick above, the maps $$ \text{Spec }  L ^{-1} ( A _ { x_{j} } ) \to    \text{Spec }  L ^ { -  1  }  B_{i}  $$
actually come from some maps 
$$    (  B_{i}  ) _ { r_{ij} }  \to  (  A_{x_{j} }  ) _ {r_{ij} }    \quad     r_{ij}  \in  T     $$
by localizing at $ T $. By taking the product $ r $ of all the $ r_{ij} $, we see that we have maps $$  
 \left  ( \bigcup _ { j }  \text{ Spec } A_{x_{j} }  \right )  \times_{S}  \text{ Spec } R_ { r }  \to    \left (  \bigcup _ { i }   \text {Spec } B  _ { i }   \right  )   \times _ {S}  \text{ Spec } R_{r}   $$
Now, the union of $ \text{ Spec } B_{j} $ is $ Y $ by definition, but $ \bigcup _ { i }  \text{Spec }  A _ { x_{i} } $ is not necessarily a cover of $ X = \text{Spec } A $.   However, we can fix   this as follows.

Inside $ A $, we have $$ D( x_{1} )  \cup D(x_{2} )  \cup \ldots  \cup D(x_{n} )  = D( x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} ) = D( \alpha ) $$
for some $ \alpha \in R $, since $ x_{i}/1 $  generate   the unit ideal in $  L 
 ^ { - 1  } A $. By further   localizing $ R $ at $ \alpha $,  we  can  make   sure that $ D(x_{i} )  $  forms a cover of $ \text{Spec }  A $.

Answer (score 4):

Let $ p : X \to S $ and $ q : Y \to S $ be the structure maps. We can replace $ S $ with   any    open affine $  W   $ around $ s $, $ X $ with $ p ^{-1}  (  W )  $ and $ Y $ with $ q ^ { - 1  }   (   W   )  $ while the hypothesis still holds. Henceforth, assume that $ S $ is the spectrum of a Noetherian ring $ R $ and $ s $ is the prime $ \mathfrak{p} $ in $ R $. Set $ L = R   \setminus  \mathfrak{p}  $.

***Claim 1.*** The scheme $ X \times O _{ S,s }$ is topologically a subspace of $ X $ that is the union of all the fibers $ f^{-1}(t) = X_{t}  =  X  \times  _ { S }  k(t) $ where $ t $ is a generization of $ s $   i.e.   $ s \in    \overline { \left \{ t  \right \} }    $.    Moreover, any open subscheme of $ X \times O_{S,s} $  is   isomorphic to    $ U \times_{s}  \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ for some open subscheme  $ U  $  of $ X $.

***Proof.*** Let us denote the underlying topological space of $ X \times _ { S }   \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ by   $ T $.

For the first part, it suffices to show the claim when $ X $ is affine (Why?). Suppose $ X = \text{Spec } A $. Then, $ X \times _ { S  }  \mathcal{O}_{S,s}   =   \text{Spec } ( A \otimes R _ {   \mathfrak{p} } )  =   \text{Spec } (  L ^ { - 1 }      A  ) $. Since this is a localization, the space $  T  $ is a subspace of $ X $. Moreover,  $ T $ consists of exactly those primes $ \mathfrak{q} $ of $ A $ whose inverse image under the ring map $ R \to A $ is a prime $ \mathfrak{p} ' \subset \mathfrak{p}  $ i.e. $ T $ is the pre-image of those points in $ S $ which are generizations   of $ \mathfrak { p } $.  This proves the first half of the claim.

Suppose now that $ V $ is an open subscheme of $ X  \times _{S } \mathcal{O}_{S,s}  $.   Then, from the proof above of the first part, $ V $ as a topological susbspace is equal to $ U \cap  T $ for some open subset $ U $ of $ X      $. Now, $ U $ has a unique  open  sub-scheme structure inherited from $ X $ and the  scheme  $  U  \times  _ {  S }   \mathcal{O}_{S,s}  $, which is an open subscheme of $ X  \times  _ { S }  \mathcal{O}_{S,s}  $,  has the same underlying topological space as $ V     $.   Since  the  open  subscheme  structures are unique, we must have  $  V  \cong   U  \times _ { S}   \mathcal{O}_{S,s}   $.    $ \square   $

Henceforth, we shall call the scheme $ X \times _ { S } \mathcal{O} _ { S, s} $ the *thick fiber* of $ X $ at  $ s $ and denote it by $    ^ t X _ { s  }    $. So, we are given a map   $$    \varphi :\ ^{t}{X} _ { s}  \to  \ ^ t Y _ { s } . $$
and the problem is to "expand this map" around the subspaces $ ^t{X} $, $ ^{t}Y $ to $ p^{-1}(U) $, $ q^{-1}(U) $ for some open affine $ U \ni s $ in $ S $.

Since $ X $, $ Y $  are  finite  type $ R $-schemes, both $ X $ and $ Y $ are quasi-compact. Let $    U  =    \text{Spec }   A   $ be an aribrary   open affine  subset of $ X $  and $  V _{i}  = \text{Spec }   A    _{ i }  $, $ 1 \leq i \leq n $   be a finite  open affine cover of $ Y $, and $ V_{i} ' =   \text{Spec } A_{i} \otimes R_{\mathfrak{p}} $ be the corresponding covering of the thick fiber of $ Y $ at $ s $.  We   can cover $  U  \cap  \varphi ^ { - 1 } ( V_{i}  ' ) $ for each $ i = 1, \ldots, n $ by finitely many distinguished open subsets of $ \text{Spec }   L^{-1}   A = U \times _ { S }  \mathcal{O}_{S,s}  $,  say altogether  by $$    U_{j}   '  =  \text{Spec }   A_{\mathfrak{p}, g_{j}}  \text{ for  } 1 \leq    j  \leq    N   ,  \quad g_{j}  \in  A   _ { \mathfrak{p} }  $$
so that each of   these  open   affines      lands inside $   V_ { i }   '     $ for some $ i  $.   Then, since $ D(g_{j}) $ cover $  \text{Spec }  L ^ { -1 }  A   
 $,   $ g_{j} $ generate the unit ideal in $  A  _ { \mathfrak{p} } $. Suppose that  $$ g_ { j }     =    \frac{x_{j } }  { y_{ j }    } $$
where $ x_{j} \in  A  $, $ y_{j} \in  L  $. Then, from the remark just made, there are $ \frac  {  a _{j} }   {  z_{j} }  \in  L ^ { - 1 }  A  $ where $ a_{j} \in  A  $, $ z_{j} \in  L   $ for $ j   = 1 , \ldots,  N   $ such that $$  \sum_{i}   \frac{ a _{i} }  { z_{i} }  \cdot  \frac{x_{i} } { y_{i} }  = 1  ,   $$
which, after  clearing all denominators, implies that the ideal generated by $ x_{1} ,  \ldots  ,   x_{N}   $ in $  A  $ is generated by  the image of an element $  \alpha \in \eta ( L )  $, where $ \eta : R \to A $ is the ring map. If we set $ U_{j} =  \text{Spec } A_{x_{j} } $, then we cannot say that $ U_{j} $  necessarily    make a cover of $ U $.  If  however    one  replaces $$  R  \rightsquigarrow  R_{ \alpha  } , $$
(and $ X $, $ Y $, $ V_{i}  $, $ U $ by appropriate open  subschemes)
to begin with, $ U_{j} $ can now be assumed to cover $ U $ (since $  x_{i} $ now generate the unit ideal in $ A $).

Since   $ X $ is quasi-compact, we can do the same argument for each open subset in a finite cover of $ X $. We thus end up with an affine cover $  \text{Spec }  A_{j} $ of $ X $ for $ 1 \leq j \leq m  $, a  cover $ \text{Spec }  B_{i} $ of $ Y $ for $ 1 \leq i \leq n $, and a finite collection of ring maps   $ B_{i}   \otimes  R _ { \mathfrak { p } }   \to A_{j}    \otimes  R  _ { \mathfrak{p} } $ for pairs $ (i,j) $ in some set  $  I \subset \left {1, \ldots, n  \right \}   \times  \left\{ 1, m \right  \}    $  that agree on intersections.

*Claim 2.*   Let $ A $ and $ B   $ be $ R $-algebras where $ R $ is a Noetherian ring and let $ \mathfrak{p} $ a prime of $ R $. Suppose that we have a ring map $    \phi   :     B   \otimes  R_{  \mathfrak{ p } } \to  A   \otimes     R _ { \mathfrak{p} }  $. If  $ B $ is finitely generated, there exists a $ r \in R  \setminus \mathfrak{p} $ such that $  \phi   $ is obtained from a map $  \psi :   B _  { r  } \to  A_{ r } $ by localizing to $  R  \setminus  \mathfrak{p}  $.  Moreover, if $ r' $  and $ \psi '   :     B _ { r '}  \to A_{r' } $ are any other such pair, then  the maps so defined from $ B_{rr' }   \to  A_{rr' } $ by localizing $ \psi , \psi '   $  are the same.

*Proof.*   Suppose that $ B  =  R[t_{1}, \ldots, t_{n} ] / ( b_{1} , \ldots, b _ {  m   }   ) $ where $ b_{1}, \ldots, b_{m} \in R [t_{1},  \ldots,  t_{n} ] $. Consider the induced map $ \chi : R  _ { \mathfrak{p}   }  [ t_{1} , \ldots, t_{n} ] \to A_{ \mathfrak{p}  }  $. Suppose that $$ t_{i} \mapsto  \frac{a_{i}}{s_{i}}       \quad  \quad   \quad   \text{for } i = 1, \ldots, n   $$
and let $ s   =  s_{1} s_{2} \ldots   s_{n}  $. Define a map $   \chi '  :  R_{s}  [ t_{1}  ,  \ldots,   t_{n }   ]  \to A_{  s  } $ by $$        t_{i}   \mapsto 
  \frac{a_{i}  s_{1}  \cdots  s_{i-1}  s_{i+1}    \cdots   s_{n}  }   {  s }  
    \quad  \quad   \quad \text{      for } i = 1 , \ldots, n   $$
and suppose that under $  \chi '   $,   $$       b_{j}   \mapsto   \frac{ a_{j} ' } {  s_{j}  '    }    \text{ for } j = 1, \ldots, m  . $$ 
It is clear that $  \chi  $   is obtained from $ \chi   '  $ after localizing to $ R \setminus  \mathfrak{p} $. Thus, each $  \frac{ a_{j}  ' } {   s _{j}  ' } $ becomes a zero in $    A  _ {  \mathfrak { p }     } $, which means that there are   $ r_{j}    \in  R  \setminus  \mathfrak{p} $ such that $ r _{j}   \cdot   a_{j} ' = 0 $.  Thus, taking $ r =  s  \cdot r _{1}    r _{2} \cdots   r  _  {m} $,  we see that the induced map  $$   R_{r} [  t_{1} ,  \ldots ,    t_{n} ]  \to A_{r}   $$ 
sends $ b_{j} $ to zero,  and thus further induces a map $$ \psi :   B   _ { r } \to  A_{ r }       .   $$
This map $ \psi $ clearly localizes to $ \phi  $  and is the desired  map.     The fact that any two   such  maps are compatible  is     straightforward.      $ \square $

In light of Claim 2 above, we can find finitely many $ r_{ij}      $   for  $ (i, j ) \in I  $  such that the maps $ B_{j}  \otimes  R_{ \mathfrak{p} }   \to  A_{i}   \otimes   R _ { \mathfrak { p}   }   $   are   localizations     of  some  maps  $$   B _ { j }  \otimes  R  _ {  r _ { ij }  }  \to  A_{i}   \otimes  R  _  {  r  _ { i j } }   $$ which agree on common open subsets.  By taking the product of $  r_ { i j } $ to be $ r $, we  obtain a common   neighbourhood  $   W    =    D(r) $ in $  \text{Spec }  R   $ and compatible maps $  B_ { j } \otimes   R_{r}  \to  A_{i}  \otimes  R_{r}  $. This amounts to giving a map  $$    p^{-1} (  W  )  \to   q ^ {- 1} (  W  )  $$
and which is the desired  claim.

***Remark 1.***  We only needed the  map $ X   \to   S     $ to   be  quasi-compact instead of finite type in  the proof.

It is interesting to note that no hypothesis on $ X $ was needed in [Extending a morphism of schemes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259876/extending-a-morphism-of-schemes), but is crucial here for the result to hold.   The  necessity of some hypothesis on $ X $ was pointed out to me Arnav Tripathy and Koji Shizimu and an explicit counterexample given by the latter is reproduced below.

Take $ S =   \text{Spec } \mathbb{Z} $, $ s $ the generic point of $ S  $, $ Y =  \text{Spec } \mathbb{Z} [t] $ and $ X = \bigsqcup _ { i \in \mathbb{N} }       X_{i}  $ where $ X_{i} =  \text{Spec } \mathbb{Z} [ t]  $. Then, $ X \times 
 \mathcal{ O } _{S,s}  =   \text{Spec } \mathbb{Q} [t ] $ and $  X \times _ { S }  \mathcal{O} _{ S, s } =    \bigsqcup_{ i \in \mathbb{N} } \mathbb{Q} [ t ] $. We can then define a map $ \varphi : X \times _ { S  }  \mathcal{O}_{S,s}  \to Y  \times  \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ by defining the map on the  $ i  $-th copy of $  \mathbb{Q} [ t] $ to $ \mathbb{Q} [ t] $ which sends $ t $ to $ t / i $. Since the open subsets  of  $  \text{Spec }  \mathbb{Z}     $   are of the  form $  \text{Spec }  \mathbb{Z}  [ 1 / N   ] $, it is impossible to find an open subset $ U $ of $ S $ such that $ \varphi $ is obtained from some $ X \times U \to Y \times U  $, as there are   infinitely many denominators involved.

***Remark 2.*** The claim that open subsets of $ X \times \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ are of the form $ U \times  \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ isn't true if $   \mathcal{O}  _   { S , s } $ is replaced by  an  arbitrary    $ S $-scheme $ Z $. See the counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844159/morphism-from-product-of-schemes).

***Remark 3.*** One may wonder that if any open subset of $ X \times  \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ is of the form $ U \times _{ S}  \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ for some open subset $ U $ of $ X  $, how does one write $ X \times_{S} W $ in the said form where $ W $ is an open subset of $ \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $? This may seem counter-intuitive as first, but we can proceed as follows.

Since $  \text{Spec }  \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $ is a subspace of $ S $ (it is, in fact, the intersection of all open subsets of $ S $ containing $ s $), any open subset $  W  $ of  $  \text{Spec }   \mathcal{O}_{S,s}  $ is obtained by intersecting some open subset $ V $ of $ S $ with this subspace. Let $ U  = p ^ { - 1 } ( V ) $. Then, $  X \times _   {  S  }  W  =  U  \times _ { S } \mathcal{O}_{S,s}   $.

Comment: I have a question about the end of Claim 2, when you say that the localizations of $\psi$ and $\psi'$ are the same. What is the reason of that? We just know that the induced maps $B_{rr'}\otimes R_{\frak{p}}\rightarrow A_{rr'}\otimes R_{\frak{p}}$ are the same. Thank you

Comment: @BernyPiffaro They are not the same, but they are the same if we further localize them. Because the two maps are essentially determined by a finite number of elements in $A_{rr^\prime}$, if they agree in $A_{rr^\prime}\otimes R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, then we can lift the equality to some $A_{rr^\prime t}$ just like above.

Comment: @ZWu Ok, now it is clear. Thanks :)

Comment: Just after the proof of the claim 2: [... localizations of some maps $B_j \otimes R_{r_{ij}}\to A_i \otimes R_{r_{ij}}$ which agree on common open subsets.] Can you explain why they agree on common open subsets? I mean there could be $(i_1,j)$ and $(i_2,j)$ in $I$ with different $i_1\neq i_2$. It doesn't seem trivial to me.

Comment: @BernyPiffaro The problem is not on the side of $B$, but on the side of $A$. Say we have all those $B$'s are the same. But we may have $B\otimes R_r\to A_{i_1}\otimes R_r$ not agree with $B\otimes R_r\to A_{i_2}\otimes R_r$ on common opens.

Comment: @ZWu I'll delete the previous comment, I've been imprecise indeed. We are left with lots of "local morphisms" $\varphi_{ij}: B_j\otimes R_r\rightarrow A_i\otimes R_r$ (we can choose wlog all $R_{ij}$ are the same). These correspond to scheme morphisms $\phi_{ij}: Spec\ A_i\otimes R_r\rightarrow Spec\ B_j\otimes R_r$. Remember that the $Spec\ B_j\otimes R_r$ are open subschemes of $Y\times Spec\ R_r$ so we actually have many scheme morphisms $Spec\ A_i\otimes R_r\rightarrow Y\times Spec\ R_r$... (it continues in the next comment)

Comment: Assume $Y$ is affine. We want the morphisms to coincide on $Spec\ A_{i_1}\otimes R_r \cap Spec\ A_{i_2}\otimes R_r$ up to further choices for $r$. Since $Y=Spec\ B$ is affine, it is sufficient to show we can choose $r$ such that the two ring morphisms $B\otimes R_r \rightarrow A_{i_1}\otimes R_r\rightarrow C\otimes R_r$ and $B\otimes R_r \rightarrow A_{i_2}\otimes R_r\rightarrow C\otimes R_r$ (where $Spec\ C$ is an affine open subscheme of $Spec\ A_{i_1}\cap Spec\ A_{i_2}$) are the same. As $B$ is a fin. gen. $R$-algebra we just have to make the images of the generators coincide.

Comment: This last thing should be quite easy. Unfortunately I do not know how to proceed if $Y$ is not affine. To make the reasoning work we should have the images of the two morphisms conteined in an affine open. @ZWu Do you have any idea?

Comment: @BernyPiffaro Yes, but it is clearly too long. I will post a complete answer later.

Comment: @BernyPiffaro Answer posted, come check it out.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$We may shrink $S$ to any open neighborhood of $s$. Let's first deal
with the case everything is affine.

**Claim 1:** Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $\mathfrak{p}\in\Spec R$,
$A,B$ be two finite type $R$-algebras, and $\varphi:A_{\mathfrak{p}}\to B_{\mathfrak{p}}$
be a map of $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$-algebra. Then there exists $f\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$
and an $R_{f}$-algebra map $\varphi^{\prime}:A_{f}\to B_{f}$ s.t.
$\varphi^{\prime}\otimes\mathrm{id}_{R_{\mathfrak{p}}}=\varphi$.
If $(g,\psi)$ is another such pair, then there exists $h\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$
s.t. the maps $A_{fgh}\to B_{fgh}$ induced by $\varphi^{\prime}$
and $\psi$ agree. Moreover if $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, then
we can pick $(f,\varphi^{\prime})$ s.t. $\varphi^{\prime}$ is an
isomorphism.

*Proof:* Since $R$ is Noetherian and $A$ is of finite type,
$A$ must be finitely presented. Say $A=\frac{R[T_{1},\dots,T_{n}]}{(g_{1},\dots,g_{m})}$.
Then $\varphi$ is uniquely determined by a finite set of relations:
$\varphi(T_{i})=\frac{b_{i}}{r_{i}}\in B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $\varphi(g_{i})=0\in B_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
We can lift those relations to $B_{f}$ for some $f\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$
and hence lift $\varphi$ to $\varphi^{\prime}:A_{f}\to B_{f}$. Similarly
if $(g,\psi)$ is another such pair, we have $\forall i,\varphi^{\prime}(T_{i})=\psi(T_{i})$
in $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$, and we can lift the relations to $B_{fgh}$
for some $h\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$. It follows that $\varphi^{\prime}=\psi$
over $R_{fgh}$.

If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism with inverse $\psi=\varphi^{-1}:B_{\mathfrak{p}}\to A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Then there exists $(f,\varphi^{\prime})$ for $\varphi$ and $(g,\psi^{\prime})$
for $\psi$. By above proof we may assume $f=g$. Now $\psi^{\prime}\circ\varphi^{\prime}=\mathrm{id}_{A_{f}}$
and $\varphi^{\prime}\circ\psi^{\prime}=\mathrm{id}_{B_{f}}$ over
$R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, so there exists $g\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$
s.t. the equalities hold over $R_{fg}$. The result follows.$\square$

We will also use Claim 2 and Claim 3 which are stated and proved at
the end of this answer.

**Notation:** for any $S$-scheme $Z$, denote $Z\times_{S}\Spec\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$
by $Z^{\prime}$. For any integer $m\geq1$, denote $\{1,\dots,m\}$
by $[m]$. If $T_{i}$ and $T_{j}$ are open in a scheme $T$, denote
$T_{ij}:=T_{i}\cap T_{j}$.

Next we want to show the following: after shrinking $S$ finitely
many times,

1. there exists finite open affine coverings $\{X_{j}\}_{j\in[m]},\{Y_{i}\}_{i\in[n]}$
   for $X$ and $Y$ respectively and a function $\sigma:[m]\to[n]$
   s.t. $\forall j\in[m],\varphi(X_{j}^{\prime})\subset Y_{\sigma(j)}^{\prime}$,
   and we denote the induced restricted map by $\varphi_{j}:X_{j}^{\prime}\to Y_{\sigma(j)}^{\prime}$
   (Claim 2 is used here). Thus for each $j\in[m]$ there exists $f_{j}:X_{j}\to Y_{\sigma(j)}$
   associated with $\varphi_{j}$ by Claim 1 after shrinking $S$ finitely
   many times.
2. for each pair $\alpha,\beta\in[n]$, there exists a cover of $Y_{\alpha\beta}$
   by finite open subsets $\{Y_{\alpha\beta k}\}_{k\in[n_{\alpha\beta}]}$
   distinguished in both $Y_{\alpha}$ and $Y_{\beta}$;
3. for each pair $\alpha,\beta\in[m]$, there exists a cover of $X_{\alpha\beta}$
   by finite open subsets $\{X_{\alpha\beta k}\}_{k\in[m_{\alpha\beta}]}$
   distinguished in both $X_{\alpha}$ and $X_{\beta}$, and a function
   $\sigma_{\alpha\beta}:[m_{\alpha\beta}]\to[n_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)}]$
   s.t. for each $k\in[m_{\alpha\beta}]$, $\varphi(X_{\alpha\beta k}^{\prime})\subset Y_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)\sigma_{\alpha\beta}(k)}^{\prime}$.
   By Claim 3, we can see that, $f_{\alpha}(X_{\alpha\beta k})\subset Y_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)\sigma_{\alpha\beta}(k)}$
   and $f_{\beta}(X_{\alpha\beta k})\subset Y_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)\sigma_{\alpha\beta}(k)}$
   after shrinking $S$ finitely many times. So them induce two maps
   $X_{\alpha\beta k}\to Y_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)\sigma_{\alpha\beta}(k)}$
   agreeing over $\Spec\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$, thus we can assume they are
   the same by shrinking $S$ (Claim 1).

Note that everything is Noetherian so quasi-compact. Clearly $Y$
admits a finite open affine covering $\{Y_{i}=\Spec A_{i}\}_{i\in[n]}$
s.t. for each pair $\alpha,\beta\in[n]$, $Y_{\alpha\beta}$ is covered
by finite open subsets $\{Y_{\alpha\beta k}\}_{k\in[n_{\alpha\beta}]}$
distinguished in both $Y_{\alpha}$ and $Y_{\beta}$. Similarly $X$
admits a finite open affine covering $\{Z_{j}=\Spec B_{j}\}_{j\in[p]}$.
Fix $j\in[p]$, $Z_{j}^{\prime}$ is covered by $\{\varphi^{-1}(Y_{i}^{\prime})\cap Z_{j}^{\prime}\}_{i\in[n]}$,
and each of them is again covered by finitely many distinguished affine
opens of $Z_{j}^{\prime}$, say $Z_{j}^{\prime}=\bigcup_{i,k}U_{ijk}$.
By Claim 2 (i) and (ii), each $U_{ijk}$ is of the form $V_{ijk}^{\prime}$
where $V_{ijk}$ is distinguished affine open in $Z_{j}$ and we have
$Z_{j}=\bigcup_{i,k}V_{ijk}$ after shrinking $S$. Clearly $\varphi(V_{ijk}^{\prime})\subset Y_{i}^{\prime}$.
Let $\{X_{j}\}_{j\in[m]}=\{V_{ijk}\}_{i,j,k}$. Then we have shown
part (1) and part (2).

Fix a pair $\alpha,\beta\in[m]$. Note that $\{Y_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)k}\}_{k\in[n_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)}]}$
covers $Y_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)}$. Also $X_{\alpha\beta}$
admits a finite open covering $\{\widetilde{X}_{\alpha\beta k}\}_{k\in[q_{\alpha\beta}]}$
distinguished in both $X_{\alpha}$ and $X_{\beta}$. Similarly, fix
$k\in[q_{\alpha\beta}]$, $\widetilde{X}_{\alpha\beta k}^{\prime}$
is covered by $\{\varphi^{-1}(Y_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)k^{\prime}}^{\prime})\cap\widetilde{X}_{\alpha\beta k}^{\prime}\}_{k^{\prime}\in[n_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)}]}$,
and each of them is again covered by finitely many distinguished affine
opens of $\widetilde{X}_{\alpha\beta k}^{\prime}$, say $\widetilde{X}_{\alpha\beta k}^{\prime}=\bigcup_{k^{\prime},t}U_{\alpha\beta kk^{\prime}t}$.
By Claim 2 (i) and (ii), each $U_{\alpha\beta kk^{\prime}t}$ is of
the form $V_{\alpha\beta kk^{\prime}t}^{\prime}$ where $V_{\alpha\beta kk^{\prime}t}$
is distinguished affine open in $\widetilde{X}_{\alpha\beta k}$ and
we have $\widetilde{X}_{\alpha\beta k}=\bigcup_{k^{\prime},t}V_{\alpha\beta kk^{\prime}t}$
after shrinking $S$. Clearly $\varphi(V_{\alpha\beta kk^{\prime}t})\subset Y_{\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)k^{\prime}}.$Let
$\{X_{\alpha\beta k}\}_{k\in[m_{\alpha\beta}]}=\{V_{\alpha\beta kk^{\prime}t}\}_{k,k^{\prime},t}$.
This completes part (3).

It follows that for all $\alpha,\beta\in[m]$, for all $k\in[m_{\alpha\beta}]$,
we have $f_{\alpha}|_{X_{\alpha\beta k}}=f_{\beta}|_{X_{\alpha\beta k}}$
(assuming the target is $Y$). Thus $f_{\alpha}|_{X_{\alpha\beta}}=f_{\beta}|_{X_{\alpha\beta}}$
(assuming the target is $Y$). Hence $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in[m]}$
(target $Y$) glues to a desired morphism $f:X\to Y$.

Next we show the part of about lifting an isomorphism. Note that we can assume $S$ is affine. By the same
method in the proof of Claim 1, it suffices to show that if $(D(g_{1}),f_{1}:X_{D(g_{1})}\to Y_{D(g_{1})})$
and $(D(g_{2}),f_{2}:X_{D(g_{2})}\to Y_{D(g_{2})})$ are two pairs
satisfying the conditions in (a), then there exists $h\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$
s.t. $f_{1}=f_{2}$ over $D(g_{1}g_{2}h)$.

By shrinking $S$ to $D(g_{1}g_{2})$, we can assume $S=D(g_{1})=D(g_{2})$
and we have $f_{1},f_{2}:X\to Y$ inducing $\varphi$. Again $Y$
admits a finite open affine covering $\{Y_{i}=\Spec A_{i}\}_{i\in[n]}$.
For each $i\in[n]$, $\varphi^{-1}(Y_{i}^{\prime})=f_{1}^{-1}(Y_{i})^{\prime}=f_{2}^{-1}(Y_{i})^{\prime}=(f_{1}^{-1}(Y_{i})\cap f_{2}^{-1}(Y_{i}))^{\prime}$.
By Claim 2 (iv), we have $f_{1}^{-1}(Y_{i})=f_{1}^{-1}(Y_{i})\cap f_{2}^{-1}(Y_{i})=f_{2}^{-1}(Y_{i})$
after shrinking $S$. Denote $T_{i}:=f_{1}^{-1}(Y_{i})=f_{2}^{-1}(Y_{i})$.
It suffices to show that we can shrink $S$ finitely many times so
that $f_{1}|_{T_{i}}=f_{2}|_{T_{i}}$ (with target $Y_{i}$) for each
$i$. So we may assume $Y$ is affine. Let $\{X_{i}\}_{i\in[m]}$
be a finite open affine covering of $X$. By Claim 1, for each $i\in[m]$,
we have that $f_{1}|_{X_{i}}=f_{2}|_{X_{i}}$ by shrinking $S$ to
a distinguished open subset. Then we just do this finitely many times
so that $f_{1}=f_{2}$. The result follows. $\square$.

---

**Claim 2:** Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $\mathfrak{p}\in\Spec R$,
$A$ be a finitely generated $R$-algebra. Then:

- (i) Any distinguished affine open subset of $\Spec A_{\mathfrak{p}}$
  is of the form $\Spec(A_{a})_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for some $a\in A$;
- (ii) If $\Spec A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is covered by $D(a_{i})_{\mathfrak{p}}:=\Spec(A_{a_{i}})_{\mathfrak{p}}$
  for $1\leq i\leq n$, then there exists $f\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$
  s.t. $\Spec A_{f}$ is covered by $D(a_{i})_{f}:=\Spec(A_{a_{i}})_{f}$
  for $1\leq i\leq n$.
- (iii) If there exist an open subset $U\subset\Spec A$ s.t. $U_{\mathfrak{p}}:=U\times_{\Spec R}\Spec R_{\mathfrak{p}}=\Spec A_{\mathfrak{p}}$,
  then there exists $f\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$ s.t. $U_{f}:=U\times_{\Spec R}\Spec R_{f}=\Spec A_{f}$.
- (iv) If $X$ is of finite type over $R$ and there exists an open subset
  $U\subset X$ s.t. $U_{\mathfrak{p}}=X_{\mathfrak{p}}$, then there
  exists $f\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$ s.t. $U_{f}=X_{f}$.

*Proof:* (i) Let $D(\frac{a}{r})\subset\Spec A_{\mathfrak{p}}$
with $a\in A,r\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$. Since $r$ is a unit
in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, we have $(A_{\mathfrak{p}})_{\frac{a}{r}}=(A_{\mathfrak{p}})_{a}=(A_{a})_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
(ii) Note that $\Spec(A_{a_{i}})_{\mathfrak{p}}=\Spec(A_{\mathfrak{p}})_{a_{i}}$.
There exists $\frac{b_{i}}{r_{i}}\in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ s.t.
$$
1=\sum_{i}\frac{b_{i}}{r_{i}}\cdot a_{i}\in A_{\mathfrak{p}}.
$$
Then we can lift this relation to $A_{f}$ for some $f\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$.
The result follows. (iii) follows from (i) and (ii) and the fact that
$U$ is quasi-compact. (iv) Since $X$ is quasi-compact, $X$ admits
a finite open affine covering $\{X_{i}\}_{i\in[m]}$. For each $i\in[m]$,
denote $U_{i}:=X_{i}\cap U$. Then $(U_{i})_{\mathfrak{p}}=(X_{i})_{\mathfrak{p}}\cap U_{\mathfrak{p}}=(X_{i})_{\mathfrak{p}}\cap X_{\mathfrak{p}}=(X_{i})_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
By (iii), there exists $f_{i}\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$ s.t. $(U_{i})_{f_{i}}=(X_{i})_{f_{i}}$.
Let $f=\prod_{i}f_{i}$, then $U_{f}=X_{f}$. $\square$

**Claim 3:** Let $R$ be a ring and $\mathfrak{p}\in\Spec R$,
$A,B$ be two $R$-algebras. Let $a\in A,b\in B$, and $\varphi:A\to B$
be a map of $R$-algebra s.t. it induces a map $\psi:(A_{\mathfrak{p}})_{a}\to(B_{\mathfrak{p}})_{b}$
(i.e. the image of $a$ is invertible in $(B_{\mathfrak{p}})_{b}$).
Then there exists $f\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$ s.t. $\varphi$
induces a map $\phi:(A_{f})_{a}\to(B_{f})_{b}$ (i.e. the image of
$a$ is invertible in $(B_{f})_{b}$).

*Proof:* Say $\psi(a)\cdot\frac{b^{\prime}}{b^{m}\cdot f^{\prime}}=\varphi(a)\cdot\frac{b^{\prime}}{b^{m}\cdot f^{\prime}}=1\in(B_{\mathfrak{p}})_{b}$
with $m\geq1,f^{\prime}\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$. Clearly there
exist $f\in R\backslash\mathfrak{p}$ s.t. the equality holds in $(B_{f})_{b}$.
The result follows.$\square$

Comment: Thank you for you answer (I'll read it as soon as I can), but I seems to me a bit too complicated. I'll try to post a different idea of solution that I hope will work (then let me know if you agree)

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is based on what previously discussed)
In the comments it is remarked we have lots of maps $\varphi_i: Spec\ A_i\otimes R_r \rightarrow Y\times Spec\ R_r$. If we localize we get the map $Spec\ A_i\otimes R_p\rightarrow Spec\ B_j\otimes R_p\hookrightarrow Y\times Spec\ R_p$ given in the hypothesis.

**Lemma**
Let $\varphi: X\times Spec\ R_p \rightarrow Y\times Spec\ R_p$ as in our hypothesis and $f,g:X\times Spec\ R_r \rightarrow Y\times Spec\ R_r$ two maps whose localizations coincide with $\varphi$. Then $f$ and $g$ are the same map (up to shrinking $Spec\ R_r$).

*Proof*
As it was pointed out in the first answer there exist affine opens $Spec\ A_i$ and $Spec\ B_j$ resp. of $X$ and $Y$ such that $\forall\ i$ $Spec\ A_i\otimes R_p$ goes into $Spec\ B_j\otimes R_p$ through $\varphi$ for some $j$. Looking at the rings map we get a map $B_j\otimes R_p\rightarrow A_i\otimes R_p$ and so maps $\hat{f},\hat{g}: B_j\otimes R_r\rightarrow B_j\otimes R_p\rightarrow A_i\otimes R_p$ (this just considering the commutative diagram given by the fibre products). Up to further localizations one can assume both maps factorize through $B_j\otimes R_r\rightarrow A_i\otimes R_r\rightarrow A_i\otimes R_p$ so that we can assume $f,g:Spec\ A_i\otimes R_r \rightarrow Spec\ B_j\otimes R_r \hookrightarrow Y\times Spec\ R_r$. Restricting again $Spec\ R_r$ (and working with the ring maps) we can adfirm $f=g$ on $Spec\ A_i\otimes R_r$. You get the thesis after finitely many of such operations.

How to use this lemma?
We have maps $\varphi_i: Spec\ A_i\otimes R_r \rightarrow Y\times Spec\ R_r$ and if we consider the intersections $V_{ijr}:=Spec\ A_i\otimes R_r \cap Spec\ A_j\otimes R_r$ we obtain two maps with same localization from $V_{ijr}$ to $Y\times Spec\ R_r$. Using the lemma we can make them coicide and glue them. I think one can use the lemma above for the statement about the isomorphism too.

Comment: Good job! Looks good to me. The [Spec] sign should be used by the Declare Math Operator command. Type in \DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec} in math mode and then use \Spec to write Spec.

Comment: @ZWu Thanks! :)